# How to fix "System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"

Tags: soql, error

While cloning record i am getting the below error in the 1st line of the code, the SOQL. Can anyone help me with that.

```
XX_Segment__c desc1 = [select  Id, XXX_New_Keyword_Description__r.Description__c from XX_Segment__c where Availability_Forecast_XXX__c =:id1];
String s= desc1.XXX_New_Keyword_Description__r.Description__c;
s= s.substring(0,3);
String s1 = s+'%';
```

Regards

Comment: Your query result is having more than one record, assign them into `List<XX_Segment__c>` instead of into a single `XX_Segment__c` record

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have multiple `XX_Segment__c` records in the system that have the same value in the `Availability_Forecast_XXX__c` field. You will need to figure out which record to use by adding more criteria to your query.

You could also sort the result by `LastModifiedDate` for an example and get the last record, it all depends on your requirement and your data.

In case when multiple records are returned in the query and you want to only get the first item, you could do this:

`XX_Segment__c desc1 = [select  Id, XXX_New_Keyword_Description__r.Description__c from XX_Segment__c where Availability_Forecast_XXX__c =:id1][0];`

A better way of handling that is to assign the query to a list of records, then get the first record only when the list is not empty. It allows you to prevent any errors when the result query does not return any records:

```
XX_Segment__c desc1;
List <XX_Segment__c> segments = [select  Id, XXX_New_Keyword_Description__r.Description__c from XX_Segment__c where Availability_Forecast_XXX__c =:id1];
if (segments.isEmpty() == false)
{
    desc1 = segments[0];
}
```

If you need to clone multiple records, then you will need to run through all the results in the query:

```
for (XX_Segment__c segment : [select  Id, XXX_New_Keyword_Description__r.Description__c from XX_Segment__c where Availability_Forecast_XXX__c =:id1])
{
    XX_Segment__c desc1 = segment.clone(false, true);
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: sorry for hijacking the topic, but is it good enough to have condition like `if(segments.isEmpty() == false)` ? rather than just `if(segments.isEmpty())` ?

Comment: You mean `if (!segments.isEmpty())`? You can do either. Sometimes it's better to write as clear as possible so the other person can read and understand the code better.

Comment: Oops! yes I meant that. Agreed with that opinion @BorisBachovski