# Test class have 'System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject' error

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have this error in my code.
System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

May I know how to fix this?

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=false)
public class preventDeleteTest {
    
    @isTest
    public static void DeletetestPositive(){
        try {            
            Test.startTest();            
            Profile prof = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Marketer']; //get a profile Id
            UserRole role = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole where name LIKE 'OIC%'];
            User testUser = new User(Alias = 'STYAOAG', Email = 'slyon@tve.com.invalid', EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', FirstName = 'YFOGG', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', LastName = 'SUET LEE', LocaleSidKey = 'en_MY', ProfileId = prof.Id, TimeZoneSidKey = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', Username = 'slyeg@tve.com.devcr',UserRoleId = role.Id); 
            insert testUser;
            System.runAs(testUser) {
                
                MDR_Line_Item_Number__c MDRLineItem = new MDR_Line_Item_Number__c();
                MDRLineItem.Option__c = 'OEMi';
                MDRLineItem.Product__c = 'Nitrile PF Polymer';
                MDRLineItem.Packing_Style__c = '43';
                MDRLineItem.Brand_Name__c = 'gggkkjhk';
                MDRLineItem.Brand_Name_OBM__c= '- N/A -';
                MDRLineItem.Weight_Code__c = 'ENW035';
                MDRLineItem.Colour__c = 'BRN Blue';
                MDRLineItem.Flavour__c= 'Lemon';
                MDRLineItem.Length__c= '270mm';
                MDRLineItem.Surface__c= 'Double Embossed';
                MDRLineItem.Size__c= 'XS';
                MDRLineItem.Manufacturer_OEMi_OBM__c= 'Sentienx Sdn.Bhd.';
                MDRLineItem.CE_Cert_Number_OEMi_OBM__c= '- N/A -';
                MDRLineItem.Notify_Body_OEMi_OBM__c= '- N/A -';
                MDRLineItem.MDR_Declaration_Form__c = 'a0V5D000001rW8hUAE';

                insert MDRLineItem;
                Delete MDRLineItem;
                
                
                //Apex Trigger addError Checking
                MDR_Line_Item_Number__c testResult = [SELECT Id, IsDeleted FROM MDR_Line_Item_Number__c WHERE Id =: MDRLineItem.Id];
                system.debug('testResult.IsDeleted:::'+testResult.IsDeleted);
                system.assertEquals(true, testResult.IsDeleted);
            }
            Test.stopTest();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            system.debug('Got error::'+e);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what line? I'm guessing it's the role query...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93397/how-to-fix-system-queryexception-list-has-more-than-1-row-for-assignment-to-so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following line will query more than 1 role as it is using Like operator:

```
UserRole role = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole where name LIKE 'OIC%'];
```

This is a issue which is creating System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject.